# Grouping helm charts in kubernetes dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am using helm to deploy applications to kubernetes cluster. When several charts are deployed to a single namespace, all the deployments for all the charts are listed in a flat list in kubernetes dashboard. I am looking for a plugging for the kubernetes dashboard or any other tool which can be used for grouping the helm charts within a kubernetes namespace. Please suggest me if there is any.

Comment: Have you heard the **Kubeapps** https://github.com/kubeapps/kubeapps ? You can try it out.

Comment: Thanks @ShudiptaSharma I will give it a try.

Comment: @ShudiptaSharma This looks like great tool for installing third party helm charts and it nicely shows the status of the applications deployed. However, we cant access the pods from this UI, for that I will have to use the kubernetes dashboard again.

Comment: You didn't mention it in your description that you need to access into your pod. Btw, I am sorry that currently, I don't know about such plugin or tool.

Comment: Yes I didn't mention that in the description. Thanks for your suggestion.